# Default initial value of an integer variable in Python?

Tags: python, integer, default

What is the default initial value of an integer variable in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python doesn't allow you to reference an undefined variable, and trying to do so will raise a NameError. Often, when you create a variable that contains an integer, you will also assign some value to it.

```
>>> x = 42
```

Comment: @collegian: while you accepted this answer, I would argue that Ignacio's answer is the one you should really think about. Try to understand what a variable means in Python, then read Ignacio's answer again and you will gain some Python enlightment

Answer (score 22):

Names don't exist until bound. But the default `int`:

```
>>> print int()
0
```